# Basis function definition in a group theory book.

Tags: group-theory

I came across the following definition for the basis function of an Irreducible Representation on page 56 from the book: "Group Theory Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter".

[image]

I have basically just one question to make sure. He used the letter alpha α on equation 4.1, does α symbolizes one symmetry element in R? He didn't define α so I rely on my intuition here.

Thanks if someone knows.

Comment: I realize this is a lot of text, but it is very much prefered that you do not rely on images: they are not searchable, making the post harder to find for people for whom it may be relevant; they are not accessible (since you failed to provide an accessible description of the contents), so users who rely on screenreaders are unable to know what is on your post; and they do not adapt to different displays they way that regular text and mathjax do, so that they may appear too large or too small in someone's display (they are currently almost illegibly small in mine). Please type it up instead.

Comment: It's not that images are not permitted, but it should be possible to understand and follow your post without having access to the image, or using the accessibility description for it provided. Here, neither is a possibility.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for the remark, if you think that filling in the text manually would help getting me the answer here than I'll do that for sure.

Comment: I think you should do the right thing because it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading carefully I realized that D is the matrix representation of the symmetry operator P. Which means <$\Gamma$$\alpha$> is just a linear combination of the basis vectors (or basis functions).